# JavaFX combo box start value?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I was curious if there is a way to set a start value for a combo box so that it does not start at the topmost value. For example, I have a combo box called cbCurrentWeight with values ranging from 10 all the way to 999. I don't want 99% of users to have to scroll 100-200 numbers so they can select their weight. I would like for the combo box to start at 100 with the option to go higher or lower from there.

I do not want to set a default value for this combo box either.

Would I be better off just using a TextField and adding parameters to ensure users are entering a valid number?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a `ComboBox`, at least, not without some significant work with low-level details such as the skin. One alternative option may be an editable `Spinner`: you can keep a null initial value and customize the `SpinnerValueFactory` so that it increments or decrements from `null` to some suitable starting value. Then set a `TextFormatter` on the editor (text field) to restrict input to valid values.

Comment: Btw: you can make a `ComboBox` editable which provides a `TextField` in addition to the popup. This won't fix the issue of the initial scroll position in the popup though. If not for the difficulty of making fine grained edits I'd recommend using a `Slider` instead, since this doesn't require the user to go though a bunch of other values. (either that or a `TextField` which will allow of much faster input in most cases.)

Comment: decide what you want to achieve, then try out options, then ask ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to simply change the value to a minimum of 50lbs. The spinner option was great though, and I got it to work. I just prefer the view of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to go the simple route, a `TextField` with input validation is probably best.

Another thing you could do is create your own version. Where you display the number 100 with a (+/-) button next to it and every time a user clicks the button you increment/decrement the value. You can even add a `TextField` for step size so users can increment by 20lbs or 5lbs at a time.

Comment: that's a spinner, isn't it

Answer (score -2):

This is absolutely doable, here is the code:

```
combo.getSelectionModel().select(90);
```

This would have the combo box set itself to the 90th option. Assuming you have values 10-999 in order, this would make your combo box set itself to the 100 option.

When you call

```
combo.getSelectionModel().
```

Here are the different ways you can modify a combo boxes selection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. While this does set the value in the box to 100, it does not set the view to be at 100 when I click on the dropdown arrow. It still starts at 10.

Comment: This also sets the default selection, which the OP explicitly said they didn't want to do.